# How to set an item active in bootstrap navbar at default or after refreshing (not at click)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm using this code to highlight the url I click on from the bootstrap navbar. And it works fine when I click on an item.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var url = window.location;
        $('li.nav-item a[href="'+ url +'"]').parent().addClass('active');
        $('li.nav-item a').filter(function() {
             return this.href == url;
        }).parent().addClass('active');
    });
  </script>
```

The problem I'm having is that nothing is active when I first login or when I refresh the url. The default is nothing-active. When I set the first item as active (by adding "active" in the html code), the default is that one being active, but when I click on another item, two are now active.

What can I do?

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap 4 tab?

Comment: @Mr.Perfectionist I'm using Bootstrap 4 navbar. So each item leads to different url.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_nav_pills_toggleable&stacked=h we don't need to use jquery

Comment: @Mr.Perfectionist Thank you. So in this case the pills lead to same url, only different content. Is there a way to keep the pill-UI (I like it) but have each go to different url, while addressing my question above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to add this JS code:

```
        $('li.active').removeClass('active');
```